# Update the table when the count of particular value is more than one in SqLite

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

I have a table and I want to update the existing values when the count is greater is 1.

Here is my code :

```
  public int getCount(String clues) {
    Cursor c = null;
    try {
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String query = "select count(*) from " + TABLE_NAME + "where CLUES_VALUES = ?";
        c = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {clues});
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            return c.getInt(0);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    finally {
        if (c != null) {
            c.close();
        }
        if (db != null) {
            db.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I am checking based on the column "CLUES_VALUES" . I am getting the values from database and checking if it contains more than one similar value in the column of "CLUES_VALUES" . If it contains then it will update the entire row else it won't. 
   when I am executing the code, I am getting below error

```
     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: select count(*) from puzzl_tablewhere CLUES_VALUES = ?
```

Clues_values column contains "String values"
I don't know where I am missing. Please help .

Comment: Is it causing this error ? @VivekMishra

Comment: missing space is the cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a space in front of "where".

```
String query = "select count(*) from " + TABLE_NAME + " where CLUES_VALUES = ?";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are missing is simply a space after table name and before where.

```
String query = "select count(*) from " + TABLE_NAME + " where CLUES_VALUES = ?";
```